# PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure

Tags: python, plotly

```
a=np.linspace(start=0,stop=36,num=36)
np.random.seed(25)
b=np.random.uniform(low=0.0,high=1.1,size=36)
trace=go.Scatter(x=a,y=b)
data=trace
py.iplot(data,filename='basic')
```

I AM GETTING AN ERROR-
PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided your imports in your code snippet, and it's hard to tell why you're using `py.iplot`. But you use `import plotly.graph_objects as go` you can just replace `py.iplot(data,filename='basic')` with:

```
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

a=np.linspace(start=0,stop=36,num=36)
np.random.seed(25)
b=np.random.uniform(low=0.0,high=1.1,size=36)
trace=go.Scatter(x=a,y=b)
data=trace
# py.iplot(data,filename='basic')
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

Comment: This is was really helpful vestland..I was using py.iplot based on study material on Data Science in Linkdin Learning.. Thanks :)